# Giving/obtaining a reference to (or the name of) a UIScrollBar in a TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

This is such a mindnumbingly simple question, but apparently all the forums where actionscript is discussed (or at least all the ones on google) aren't very well managed.

I have a textArea. It has a UIScrollbar. I want to be able to reference that scrollbar. I heard there's an update() function, and that may be able to save me from the inexplicable things this damnable UIScrollbar is doing on its own.

(btw, actionscript = joke language)

Comment: Just a comment. You might have not noticed, but your question sounds like this: "I have a very simple problem, yet I cannot seem to solve it because the language is a joke and the people who discuss it can't get their stuff together". This attitude seldom helps. Instead, get a grip, try to investigate a bit for yourself (for instance, reading the API docs if you're using components is not a bad idea) and then explain your problem with as articulately and with much detail as you can (within what's reasonable); also, explaing what you've tried and didn't work usualy helps.

Answer (score 1):

When scrollbar is added to TextArea, it dispatches event ADDED. You can catch its scrollbar like this:

```
textArea.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, onTextAreaChildAdded);

private function onTextAreaChildAdded(event:Event):void {
    if (event.target is UIScrollBar) {
        //you got it
        var scrollBar:UIScrollBar = event.target as UIScrollBar;
    }
}
```

Event with scrollbar will be fired once. There is also many other stuff that adds into TextArea, so type check is needed.

Know ya jokes and be cool ^_^

Edit: wrong... Real solution seems to be just textArea.verticalScrollBar.

Comment: Why isn't this kosher? It doesn't recognize theScrollBar in the inner function:
    if (event.target is UIScrollBar) { 
        var theScrollBar:UIScrollBar = event.target as UIScrollBar;
  displayWindow.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, 
   function updateIt() { theScrollBar.update();} );
 } The scrollbar lives in the displayWindow..

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... Is code after '//you got it' executed (check it with trace)? This scrollbar must be in TextArea (if you catching its events).

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's not being hit at all.. the scrollbar isn't added programmatically, so maybe there isn't an Event.ADDED for it. that's my hunch, anyway.. I wonder if there's a way to name a UISCrollbar that isn't added programmatically. Tracing all the event.targets added shows that only the skins for the scrollbar are being noticed.. not the UIScrollbar itself. hmm.

Comment: That's strange, any DisplayObject added to stage generates this event. Are you expecting event to be happen immediately? Enter text into TextArea first until you see scrollbar...

Comment: Yeah, even on the appearance of the scrollbar it's not being noticed. My core issue is that the scrollbar doesn't lock to the bottom of the textara when the textarea width is shrunk.. if there's a long line of text, the scrollbar beings to float upward. I'd like to know why, but first I need a handle on the scrollbar.

Comment: and TextArea.verticalScrollBar()?.. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html#verticalScrollBar

Comment: var scrollBar:UIScrollBar = displayWindow.verticalScrollBar(); "Attempted access of inaccessible method verticalScrollBar through a reference with static type fl.controls:TextArea."

Comment: public function *get* verticalScrollBar - it's a getter, not method, and called without parentheses.

Comment: I think there's something about syntax I'm not understanding. "var scrollBar:UIScrollBar = displayWindow.get verticalScrollBar;"? In this case the function's not recognized. How is one supposed to use this getter?

Comment: Like this? "function get verticalScrollBar():UIScrollBar { return this._verticalScrollBar; }" gets me "expecting semicolon before", like it doesn't know what to do with the space....

Comment: If displayWindow is TextArea, it should be like this: "var scrollBar:UIScrollBar = displayWindow.verticalScrollBar;".

Answer (score 0):

In your class just write:

```
private var usb:UIScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();
```

and voilá, usb is your reference.